# Convert any to a customObject in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I cant able to convert result into IeroLocationSave object. This below cod e says -- cannot convert value of any to IeroLocationSave type in coercion

var model = IeroLocationSave!.self

```
    libName.fetchDataUsingPost(forURL: url, parameters: parameters, headerFiled: [:], completionHandler: {(result: Any?)-> Void in
        let json = result
        print("json value",json!)
        model = result! as IeroLocationSave
        print("actualResponse",result as? [String: AnyObject])
        // guard let json = result as? [String: AnyObject] else{∫

        // }


    }, failureHandler: {(result: Error?)-> Void in
        print("error", result ?? "nil")})
```

Comment: Why `model = result! as IeroLocationSave` should work? What is `IeroLocationSave`? I don't know your API, and not the class of `json`, but I'd guess it's a Dictionary. If `IeroLocationSave` is far from it, that won't do. So please give us the full error message and more info about `model/IeroLocationSave` and `json`.

Comment: IeroLocationSave - this is a custom class  & result is of type IeroLocationSave object.

Comment: What are the parameters you use when initialising a IeroLocationSave object? You need to parse those out of the JSON and then set up your initialiser properly. (By the way, try and avoid force-unwrapping optionals without checking they are non-nil first; its equivalent to pressing "I'm feeling lucky" on a search engine.)

Comment: Did you mean `result as! IeroLocationSave`?

Comment: yes i meant ---- result as! IeroLocationSave

Comment: thanks I got the issue. I was doing wrong.